# Docker: Apache in Apple Silicon M1

Tags: wordpress, docker, docker-compose

I have a `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: '1'
services:
  mariadb:
    image: 'docker.io/bitnami/mariadb:10.3-debian-10'
    ports:
      - '3307:3306'
    volumes:
      - ./db:/bitnami/mariadb
    environment:
      - MARIADB_USER=bn_wordpress
      - MARIADB_DATABASE=bitnami_wordpress
      - ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes
  wordpress:
    image: 'docker.io/bitnami/wordpress:5-debian-10'
    ports:
      - '8081:8080'
      - '8444:8443'
    volumes:
      - ./wp:/bitnami/wordpress
    depends_on:
      - mariadb
    environment:
      - MARIADB_HOST=mariadb
      - MARIADB_PORT_NUMBER=3306
      - WORDPRESS_DATABASE_USER=bn_wordpress
      - WORDPRESS_DATABASE_NAME=bitnami_wordpress
      - ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes
```

In Mac (Intel) and Linux, I run `docker-compose up` and it works perfectly.
But in Macbook M1, I installed Docker for Apple Silicon chip and updated rosetta, it prompts this at the end:

```
wordpress_1  | wordpress 15:48:36.49 INFO  ==> ** Starting Apache **
wordpress_1  | [Tue Jul 13 15:48:36.652803 2021] [core:emerg] [pid 1] (95)Operation not supported: AH00023: Couldn't create the mpm-accept mutex 
wordpress_1  | (95)Operation not supported: could not create accept mutex
wordpress_1  | AH00015: Unable to open logs
```

How can I overcome the issue? Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A bit late but have you tried adding `platform: linux/amd64`? Under both `mariadb` and `wordpress`

Comment: Thanks! This did the trick for me trying to run the docker-compose option for Bitnami Wordpress: https://hub.docker.com/r/bitnami/wordpress/

Answer (score 9):

Running `docker compose` with `platform: linux/amd64` (i.e. running under QEMU) didn't fix this problem for me. Instead (in addition), I had to add:

```
Mutex posixsem
```

... to `httpd.conf`.

Answer (score 1):

Let me share a summary for quick solution.

Connect to the container as the root user

```
docker exec -it -u 0 <container_name> /bin/bash
```

update httpd.conf file

```
echo "Mutex posixsem" >> /opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/httpd.conf
```

restart the container

```
docker restart <container_name>
```

Answer (score 1):

For devices with m1 processor, you can use `platform: linux/arm64` in docker-compose.